# TypeError: Error #1009: Null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3

I understand that it is a null object reference because the object isn't on stage, but I can't seem to correct it. Also, I have the two blocks on either side of the `else` because I couldn't have it create a variable `if = true` and the same variable `if = False`.  Would I have to first create it before the `if` statement then set it in the `if` statement? Why I am getting a null object reference error?

```
import flash.display.Stage;

if (stage.stageWidth > stage.stageHeight)
{
    var Flare21:Flare2Class = new Flare2Class();
    addChild(Flare21)
    Flare22.x = stage.stageWidth/2
    Flare22.y = stage.stageHeight/2
    Flare21.width = stage.stageHeight
    Flare21.height = stage.stageHeight
} else {
    var Flare22:Flare2Class = new Flare2Class();
    addChild(Flare22)
    Flare22.x = stage.stageWidth/2
    Flare22.y = stage.stageHeight/2
    Flare22.width = stage.stageWidth
    Flare22.height = stage.stageWidth
}
```

Comment: Which language is this? ActionScript 3?

Comment: In the two lines following `addChild(Flare21)`, you're changing the x and y property of your `Flare22` object, which does not exists. If you change these two lines to `Flare21.x = ...` and `Flare21.y = ...`, does it work?

Answer (score 1):

It's obvious that the mistake should be here:

```
var Flare21:Flare2Class = new Flare2Class();
addChild(Flare21)
Flare22.x = stage.stageWidth/2 // Flare22 IS NOT declared!
Flare22.y = stage.stageHeight/2 // Flare22 IS NOT declared!
```

Enable debugging from publish settings, so that you see on which line the error is!